# Searchbox to search newsarticles in the hub site of 10 sitecollections

Tags: search, hub-site, intranet, sharepoint-news

Our root site is our intranet sitecollection and is the hub site. There are 10 other sitecollections (HR, Legal, IT, etc..) which are associated to this hubsite. I would like to add an searchbox on the welcome page to search for newsarticles in the whole hub (10 sites). How can I do this?

ps. The searchbar on top of SharePoint Online should stay search on scope tenant.